# Expected another key-value pair at line 32, column 1 remote: ! Unable to parse package.json

Tags: node.js

im trying to deploy MERN stack application to heroku , but am having some issues doing so. Wheneve i try to deploy it gives me this error saying `Expected another key value pair at line  32 column 1` can someone please explain what this means and how i can fix it ? Thanks !!

```
{
  "name": "axios-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "google-map-react": "^1.0.4",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "node": "^10.12.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-geolocated": "^2.4.0",
    "react-geolocation": "^1.0.3",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.1.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-js": "react-scripts",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma, at the end of the "proxy" line. Like this:

```
{
  "name": "axios-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "google-map-react": "^1.0.4",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "node": "^10.12.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-geolocated": "^2.4.0",
    "react-geolocation": "^1.0.3",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.1.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-js": "react-scripts",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

Whenever you specify a comma in a json it expects a key value pair afterwards, which explains the error